# How to protect iOS p12 distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, security, apple-developer, p12, apple-developer-enterprise

Our company is going to develop InHouse apps signed with Enterprise certificate. The question is: how can we protect the certificate from being stolen/shared by our developers but at the same time let the developers use it to sign our app?

Answer (score 0):

Trust your developers.

Or develop a workflow to send the unsigned app to some in-house authority that signs it and sends it back to the developers.

Or develop an in-house signing service that does the above automatically.

Comment: Thanks! But maybe can you share some companies/services for the options 2 and 3?

Comment: A friend of mine worked for a company where local IT implemented 2. 3 is just my idea, I’m not aware of any public services implementing it.